# Data Transfer over Wi-Fi with out using Internet Data

Tags: ios, objective-c, wifi, data-transfer

How can I transfer data to other non iOS devce over Wifi without using Internet.

I want to transfer images/ other data to a non iOS device over wifi.

Comment: -ve vote please mention the reason.

Answer (score 1):

@Vineesh TP , I think you want to make a application like Xender.

It's not possible to tranfer file from Ios device to non Ios device on wifi without internet. But MultipeerConnectivity of Ios sdk allow you to transfer files between two Ios device.

To transfer file from Ios to non Ios device, you can use CocoaAsyncSocket.

Comment: I am expecting exactly you said in the first line. Any Idea about how Xender and share it works ?

Comment: Yes CocoaAsyncSocket's UDP.

Comment: When we want to transfer file from Android to Ios in Xender, we have to create hotspot in Android. We can't create hotspot in ios. So CocoaAsyncSocket's writeData method may be useful to write data on server. This written data can be read by non ios device like PC, Android (ip host) etc. @vineesh-tp I hope you understand my answer. You are doing good work.

Answer (score 0):

Google Nearby is another alternative, with explicit support for Android and iOS:

https://developers.google.com/nearby/

Comment: MultipeerConnectivity communicate with iOS devices only.

Comment: While editing the answer please mention it as an update.